# Is SurfaceView keeping keeping old image ,if I send a transparent one over old one?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a surfaceview that receive data from ndk via AnativeWindow unlock and post .

I'm interested , If for example I will send one full screen image ,that will be displayed ,  and second time I will send a same ,full size image , but with transparecy , will be my old image kept ?, and second just over it ?

I'm interested to know it this will work , cause I want old image to remain ,but my second to be over it , like a layer , and because the second is transparent , I want old one to be visible too.

Will this work?